# Running HTML only if javascript function is true

Tags: javascript, html, media-queries

I want to link to a certain stylesheet for mobile devices, and another for desktop, because with the pixel density/ large size of some of the handsets coming out now, using media queries does not always encompass all handsets like I want it to.

I want to run the following javascript:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

But I need some code.. to be an html link tag

I do not know much javascript, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for JavaScript code to insert that will add html to the page? If so can you provide a sample of the html you want to add.

Comment: Using the user agent string to identify the device is also seriously flawed. Aren't media queries designed for exactly this case? (add media–query tag)

Comment: "because with the pixel density/ large size of some of the handsets coming out now" Says who? Aren't media queries based on Pixel Width x Pixel Height? So no matter the size of the screen it will always adjust?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.write`

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=884f021ebd40">');
}
```

Make sure you place the code where you want to include the css.

Please note that it has some [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Ok, great, I'm not really a javascript kind of guy, and for this project its basically the only place I'll use it, so I think it'll do it. Thanks @ysrb especially for being patient with my lack of knowledge on javascript!

Answer (score 2):

Using plain JavaScript, you can insert a stylesheet in the `head` if your mobile user agent regex evaluates to `true` like so:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
    link=document.createElement('link');
    link.href='put your URL here';
    link.rel='stylesheet';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

`$(document.append( /* your link here */ );`

Native JS:

`document.getElementById('some-target').innerHTML = /* your link here */;`

As an alternative to ysrb's answer:

`var link = document.createElement('link');
link.type='text/css';
link.href='your.css';
link.rel='stylesheet';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);`

Comment: So on the Native JS one, what would be some-target, and what would be my link in the your link here? Which would be the link to my css file in the head of my document?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question and thought you meant an anchor tag, edited answer.

Comment: Ok well I have on for you, is there any way to do this in a media query in my css? Or should I open a new thread? @ioseph